# Not able to insert data into database using Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I am a beginner in Django and I am trying to insert values into the auth_user table. But somehow I am not able to do so. I tried to resolve but everything seems to go in vain.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
# Create your views here.
def register(request):

     if request.method == 'POST' : 
         firstname = request.POST['firstname'] 
         lastname = request.POST[ 'lastname']
         emailid= request.POST['emailid']
         username= firstname+lastname
         passwordl = request.POST['password'] 

         user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname)
         user.save()
         
         return redirect('admin/')
     else:
        return render(request, 'employee/register.html')
```

here is the template(I have downloaded this)

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Delights-Dashbord</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="{% static 'customer/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.css' %}" />

</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="Admin-reg.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">Delights</div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-user-tie"></i>
                    <span>Employee</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <!--            <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>-->
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="Admin-reg.html">Register</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="tables.html">Update</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="tables.html">Delete</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="tables.html">View</a>
                        <!--            <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-user"></i>
                    <span>Customer</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <!--            <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Utilities:</h6>-->
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-color.html">View</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-border.html">View bills</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->

        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>


                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                <div class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                                            placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search"
                                            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>


                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small"><?php  echo $nam  ?></span>
                                <!--                            <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60">-->
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Profile settings
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->

                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-8">

                            <div class="card shadow mb-8">
                                <div class="card-header py-8">
                                    <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Register Employee</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="register/" method="post">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="text-primary">
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="inputEmail4">First name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4"
                                                        name="firstname" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
                                                        name="lastname" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="inputPassword4">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4"
                                                        name="emailid" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress"
                                                        name="address" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="inputState">Sex</label>
                                                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="sex">
                                                        <option selected>Male</option>
                                                        <option>Female</option>
                                                        <option>Others</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="id-proof">Aadhaar No</label>
                                                    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}"
                                                        class="form-control" id="id-proof" name="aadharno" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="Age">Age</label>
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Age" max="100"
                                                        name="age" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="phone-no">Phone no</label>
                                                    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="form-control"
                                                        id="phone-no" name="phoneno" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="inputposition">Designation</label>
                                                    <select id="inputposition" class="form-control" name="designation">
                                                        <option selected>lol</option>
                                                        <option>lmao</option>
                                                        <option>rolf</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="phone-no">Salary</label>
                                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="no-adults" name="Salary"
                                                        required>
                                                </div>



                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit-emp"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 btn-user ">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                                <!--                             Approach -->

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <span>Copyright &copy; Delights 1995-2020</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="{% static 'customer/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'customer/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="{% static 'customer/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="{% static 'customer/js/sb-admin-2.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    <script src="{% static 'customer/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="{% static 'customer/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'customer/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

I can also notice than when I click register button I get an error that employee\register\register was called which doesnt exist, which is strange as employee\register is to be fetched.

Comment: Can you share your template file too?

Comment: Yes, thank you Ajay, I have shared the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your template & what I found is you have set the action of the form to `register/` at line `196` . So just change it to `\employee\register` & remove the foward slash from the url that you have created in `urls.py` as follows:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

**template**

```
...
<form action="\employee\register" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
...
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you missing to insert password in User table...

Another way(recommended):

**forms.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username","first_name","last_name","email"]
        labels = {'email':'Email'}
```

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        fm = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("admin/")
    else:
        fm = SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'signup.html',{"fm":fm})
```

Comment: I tired to insert values from shell and it accepts values without password and creates a row. I have been instructed not to use forms.py in my project and hence it would be nice if in can I an alternate soultion.